# Wordpress misses css and javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I've never worked with wordpress before and my brother said it was way easier then just script it so I thought I'll give it a try. Now I've made a theme and it works, but whenever I try to use a plugin it doesn't have any css or javascript associated with it. I'm probably missing something basic but it's been bothering me the last 6 hours. These are my header and footer files:

Header

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <title>Salon BellaVita</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600italic,400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css">

    <?PHP
    function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

    ?>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header ================================================== -->
<header class="clearfix header container">
    <div class="top-line navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="top-menu left">
                <li><a href="?page_id=24"><i class="icon ion ion-email"></i>&nbsp;Mail ons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon ion ion-ios7-telephone"></i>&nbsp;Tel 0181-640588</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="top-menu right">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Bella-Vita/462965717112835">
                    <i class="icon ion ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.enjoygram.com/salonbellavita">
                    <i class="icon ion ion-social-instagram-outline"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>    
<!-- End Header -->
```

Footer

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
          <p class="footercenter">
          Bella Vita
          Contact informatie: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
          someone@example.com</a>.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?> 
            </ul>     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <p class="footercenter">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Salon Bellavita" width="200" height="60" />
            </p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Does someone know what I'm missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657098/how-do-i-fix-a-wordpress-custom-theme-to-work-with-plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before your `</head>` tag, and `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` before your `</body>` tag. Plugins rely on these tags to add styles and scripts correctly.

Comment: I just knew it would be something obvious... thanks for your answer!